# Date picker dialog date format

Tags: android

I have a DatePickerDialog in my app. In the title of the dialog, the current selected date is displayed as 'Jan 30, 2012'. I wish to have the date in the title displayed like in this dialog: http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/android-datepicker-demo2.png (i.e. with a 'day').

How is this achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picker take the date format chosen by the user, which mean that you can't customize the default one.

[From User Interface page:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

Android provides a set of fully implemented widgets, like buttons, checkboxes, and text-entry fields, so you can quickly build your UI. Some widgets provided by Android are more complex, like a date picker, a clock, and zoom controls. But you're not limited to the kinds of widgets provided by the Android platform. If you'd like to do something more customized and create your own actionable elements, you can, by defining your own View object or by extending and combining existing widgets.

But take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html), for custom components:

Comment: Hmm, I know you can create custom widgets, but I wanted something specific for a date picker dialog. Ohh well, if there's nothing there, then I'll have to create my own widget. It's not your fault :)